# Cakephp site gone white after setting up .htaccess in subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

I have installed cakephp on main directory "http://mydomain.com". I want to update my site so instead of changine directly I copied the site to subfolder called "http://mydomain.com/subfolder".

I also set .htaccess as described on many forums like for root of subfolder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /subfolder/app/
    RewriteRule ^$  webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Problem is that site goes white (no contents) after setting up .htacess, but if I remove .htaccess it consider the subfolder as a page and show 404 message (Page not found).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks all viewers and helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't now if that would work, but can you check your database configurations?

Thanks